# How to open pdf from asset in Android Kitkat only?

Tags: android, pdf, android-contentprovider, android-4.4-kitkat

I am developing an android app where I have some pdf files stored in asset folder. On click of list items the files open through available pdf viewer. The following code runs fine in versions lower than Kitkat. But as Kitkat have its own Storage Access Framework(SAF) the code only opens the framework not the file.

FileContentProvider.java

```
public class FileContentProvider extends ContentProvider
{

@Override
public String getType(Uri uri)
{
    return "application/pdf";
}

@Override
public AssetFileDescriptor openAssetFile(Uri uri, String mode) throws FileNotFoundException
{   
    AssetManager am = getContext().getAssets();
    String file_name = uri.getLastPathSegment();

    if (file_name == null) throw new FileNotFoundException();
    AssetFileDescriptor afd = null;
    try
    {

        afd = am.openFd(file_name+ ".mp3");
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return afd;
}

  private final static String[] COLUMNS = {OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, OpenableColumns.SIZE};

@Override
/**
 * This function is required for it to work on the Quickoffice at Android 4.4 (KitKat)
 */
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs,      String sortOrder)
{  
    if (projection == null)
    {
        projection = COLUMNS;
    }

    String[] cols = new String[projection.length];
    Object[] values = new Object[projection.length];
    int i = 0;
    for (String col : projection)
    {
        if (OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME.equals(col))
        {
            cols[i] = OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME;
            values[i++] = uri.getLastPathSegment();
        }
        else if (OpenableColumns.SIZE.equals(col))
        {
            cols[i] = OpenableColumns.SIZE;
            values[i++] = AssetFileDescriptor.UNKNOWN_LENGTH;
        }
    }

    cols = copyOf(cols, i);
    values = copyOf(values, i);

    final MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(cols, 1);
    cursor.addRow(values);
    return cursor;
}

private static String[] copyOf(String[] original, int newLength)
{
    final String[] result = new String[newLength];
    System.arraycopy(original, 0, result, 0, newLength);
    return result;
}

private static Object[] copyOf(Object[] original, int newLength)
{
    final Object[] result = new Object[newLength];
    System.arraycopy(original, 0, result, 0, newLength);
    return result;
}


@Override
public boolean onCreate()
{
    return true;
}

@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values)
{
    return null;
}

@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs)
{
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs)
{
    return 0;
  }
}
```

The code block from where it is called:

```
 if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <19) {
                 i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);                  
            }
            else {
                 i = new Intent();

            }

            /**Open PDF Forms*/

            String fileName = "af1_version_7_december_2013.pdf";
                           i.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("content://package_name/"+fileName), "application/pdf");
                    try {
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                    catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "NO Pdf Viewer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
```

After debugging I have seen that for Kitkat the Kitkat specific code in my FileContentProvider.java is not accessed.

Please let me know if anyone have the solution to this problem. My sincere thanks in advance.

Note: This question is not duplicate as previous questions and answers were not Kitkat specefic and after my detailed search I've found that there is no solution in stack overflow to this question as of now.

Comment: Why are you trying to use an action-less `Intent` on API Level 19+? What does "the code only opens the framework not the file" mean?

Comment: adding an action in the intent didn't help. "the code only opens the framework not the file" means it does not open the pdf rather it opens something like this: [link](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-hUIWV4vSJcw/U5dEvmNkBNI/AAAAAAAACBU/1P08jrJwO80/s640/2014-06-09%252022.30.07.png)